# Netbeans 7 auto-completion

Tags: jsf, netbeans

Netbeans 7 auto-completion on jsf don't work any more, i have jar in my project and the framework is installed but don't work

Comment: Did you verify that the auto popup completion window setting is ticked? (If it is ticked, you may want to untick it, click ok to save, and then tick it again, just to be sure that what you see is the actual state.) The setting is in Options - Editor - Code completion.

Comment: it's ticket something is going wwrong with JSF jar's i think

Comment: Does code completion then work on other code? Your question isn't clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

My colleagues and I second that code completion for JSF in NB7 doesn't work fully anymore (in an xhtml, jsf tags are completed but no Java classes/methods/fields) since the last update (14 items in NB were updated, don't know which ones). Java still works fine.